# Proper wasy to handle data with Vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

So to help me understand something. For further info I'm using Laravel as a backend language and Vuejs as frontend.

A user wants to visit a page to view a specific project that hits the show method on my controller. The show method loads all data pertaining to that project to display on the page. This show page is made up of many different view partials and inside some of those partials are different Vue Components that will display different sets of data pertaining to the project. Is it better to just pass all the data through props to the different Vue components that are needed or just pass in the whole project as a prop and then reference the properties of the project inside the component? Or should I pass the project Id and then have methods to fetch the specific data for that component with use of the project id.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the three approaches you mention are perfectly valid. It depends on how you want to structure your components.

1. Do you want to use "dumb" or generic components that don't know about the structure of a "project"? Then your main component should pass relevant pieces of data to the children components.
2. Are children components specific to "projects" and not reusable anywhere else? Then passing the project reference around and each component getting the pieces of data they are interested in is also a good strategy.
3. I would probably avoid last option to avoid multiple server round trips, although it can be useful in case there is a specific part of a project that takes a lot of time to retrieve (for instance a list of sub-tasks). You could split the data fetches in two or three calls to make the main view render fast while the time-consuming query is still executing and populated when available.